# AJAX PostBack: Script controls may not be registered after PreRender

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

OK, so I have a page that has a radgrid and a form.  When creating a new record via the form and rebinding the grid, it works fine.  When initially binding the grid, it works fine.  Only when clicking a delete button in the grid, handling the custom command, and rebinding, do I get this error.

On the form, there are radtextbox, radcombobox, radspell, and other controls.  I noticed the `RadSpell.CreateChildCOntrols` in the stacktrace... does that mean that's where the error is?  I also see a reference to `ASP.views_shared_header_ascx.__Render__control1`, which is a user control and has some controls/AJAX in it.

Also, I'm binding on PreRender - this is not an issue for the rest of the app that does the same thing; and in this page, it only happens on this one spot, not in the other two spots, which are bound on prerender...

Why would this error be happening?

Thanks.

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.RegisterScriptControl[TScriptControl](TScriptControl scriptControl) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadWebControl.RegisterScriptControl() 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadWebControl.ControlPreRender() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadSpell.CreateChildControls() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptBlock.GetAjaxSettingForCurrentInitiator(RadAjaxManager currentAjaxManager) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptBlock.IsForCurrrentInitiator(Control controlToCheck, RadAjaxManager currentAjaxManager) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptBlock.IsInUpdatedControls(Control controlToCheck, RadAjaxManager currentAjaxManager) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptBlock.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at ASP.views_shared_header_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\hbweb\538e2744\52ba1acc\App_Web_header.ascx.639c3968.q1sqgwkt.0.cs:line 0
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxPanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxPanel.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxPanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.ControlRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.OurUpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderFormCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control containerControl) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmlFormWrapper.System.Web.UI.IHtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderPageCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control pageControl) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
```

Comment: Are you using advanced binding (needdatasource event) or binding using manual databind or rebind methods? Why can't you bind the grid in the itemcommand event itself immediately after you delete the row?

Comment: Manual bind.  It's more convenient to bind there based on the architecture.  It actually works 99% of the time, this is the first issue I've found with that approach.  I'll try it temporarily and see if it works.